# Kafka pipe example don't pipe all records from topic-a to topic-b

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I use the consumer and producer example called "KafkaConsumerProducerDemo" provided by **Kafka**.

I use the example `streams-app` called "pipe" provided by Kafka.

I want to realize: 
- Producer write to `topic1`
- pipe-APP consume from `topic1` and produce to `topic2`
- Consumer consume from `topic2`.

what i have done is just change the topic as following:

Consumer: `consumerThread = new Consumer(KafkaProperties.TOPIC2, "DemoConsumer", false, 500, latch);`

pipe-App: `builder.stream("topic1").to("topic2");`

Producer: `producerThread = new Producer(KafkaProperties.TOPIC, isAsync, null, false, 500, latch);`

As a result, pipe-App did't transfer all records from `topic1` to `topic2`. 
In `topic1` there are 500 records, but in `topic2` just 127!

Besides, I've tried to connect directly my `Producer` to `Consumer`, it works good! So i think the problem should be at pipe-App.
Here are the codes,

```java
public class Pipe {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-pipe");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input").to("streams-pipe-output");

        final Topology topology = builder.build();
        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        //System.out.print(topology);
        System.out.println(topology.describe());
        // attach shutdown handler to catch control-c
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread("streams-shutdown-hook") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                streams.close();
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });

        try {
            streams.start();
            latch.await();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

```java
public class KafkaConsumerDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SampleConsumer consumerThread = new SampleConsumer("streams-pipe-output");
        consumerThread.start();
    }
}
```

```java
public class SampleConsumer extends ShutdownableThread {
    private final KafkaConsumer<Integer, String> consumer;
    private final String topic;

    public static final String KAFKA_SERVER_URL = "localhost";
    public static final int KAFKA_SERVER_PORT = 9092;
    public static final String CLIENT_ID = "SampleConsumer";

    public SampleConsumer(String topic){
        super("KafkaConsumerExample", false);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KAFKA_SERVER_URL + ":" + KAFKA_SERVER_PORT);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, CLIENT_ID);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "1000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "30000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

        consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    @Override
    public void doWork() {
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(this.topic));
        ConsumerRecords<Integer, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
        for (ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> record : records) {
            System.out.println("Received message: (" + record.key() + ", " + record.value() + ") at offset " + record.offset());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String name() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInterruptible() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```java
public class KafkaProducerDemo {
    public static final String TOPIC = "streams-plaintext-input";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean isAsync = false;
        SampleProducer producerThread = new SampleProducer(TOPIC, isAsync);
        // start the producer
        producerThread.start();

    }
}
```

```java
public class SampleProducer extends Thread {
    private final KafkaProducer<Integer, String> producer;
    private final String topic;
    private final Boolean isAsync;

    public static final String KAFKA_SERVER_URL = "localhost";
    public static final int KAFKA_SERVER_PORT = 9092;
    public static final String CLIENT_ID = "SampleProducer";

    public SampleProducer(String topic, Boolean isAsync) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_SERVER_URL + ":" + KAFKA_SERVER_PORT);
        properties.put("client.id", CLIENT_ID);
        properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer");
        properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
        this.topic = topic;
        this.isAsync = isAsync;
    }

    public void run() {
        int messageNo = 1;
        while (true) {
            String messageStr = "Message_try" + messageNo;
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (isAsync) { // Send asynchronously
                producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic,
                        messageNo,
                        messageStr), new DemoCallBack(startTime, messageNo, messageStr));
            } else { // Send synchronously
                try {
                    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic,
                            messageNo,
                            messageStr)).get();
                    System.out.println("Sent message: (" + messageNo + ", " + messageStr + ")");
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // handle the exception
                }
            }
            ++messageNo;
        }
    }
}

class DemoCallBack implements Callback {

    private final long startTime;
    private final int key;
    private final String message;

    public DemoCallBack(long startTime, int key, String message) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.key = key;
        this.message = message;
    }

    /**
     * onCompletion method will be called when the record sent to the Kafka Server has been acknowledged.
     *
     * @param metadata  The metadata contains the partition and offset of the record. Null if an error occurred.
     * @param exception The exception thrown during processing of this record. Null if no error occurred.
     */
    public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception exception) {
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        if (metadata != null) {
            System.out.println(
                    "message(" + key + ", " + message + ") sent to partition(" + metadata.partition() +
                    "), " +
                    "offset(" + metadata.offset() + ") in " + elapsedTime + " ms");
        } else {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using producer and consumers while also using Streams API?

Comment: Please show all relevant property files. By default, consumer reads from latest offset, not beginning of topic

Comment: I'v updated my statement. It should be more clearly. As i'v said, i just change the topic...

Comment: Can you please link to said pipe example? And please edit again to include the properties I asked for

Comment: Did you close the KStream, by chance?

Comment: the code was uploaded.

Comment: So 1) ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG ideally should be set to false and you handle commits yourself 2) you've not defined the auto offset reset in your streams config 3) your streams config should use int serde for the key since that's what the others are using... Try adjusting some of those

Answer (score 1):

`Producer`, `Consumer` and `Stream-app` should use the same type of `serde`. 
After changing `key.serializer` from `String` to `Integer`, it worked.

Thank @cricket_007 who help me to solve the problem, and @Cahit Gungor who help me to modify my expression!